# SQL : How to get the latest value of an unordered column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to query my DB for the latest UUID (meaning the one that was inserted last). This value is generated by the application. So if I simply do..

```
select uuid from Run where <some condition>
```

then it returns multiple UUIDs. How do I get the latest one? There is an auto increment primary surrogate ID column on this table as well as Create Date, so I could just do...

```
select max(id),uuid from Run where
```

But this forces me to include that ID column but in my result set. Which I guess is not too bad but just wondering if there is an elegant way I could return just the UUID in the result set and still get the latest.

I am using MySQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sort yourself and limit the output.

```
SELECT uuid FROM Run WHERE <some_condition> ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The clearest/most explicit way is to write:

```
SELECT uuid
  FROM Run
 WHERE id =
        ( SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM Run
           WHERE <some condition>
        )
;
```

Also, please be aware that you **cannot** write what you suggested:

```
select max(id),uuid from Run where     -- Bad! Will not work!
```

because this will arbitrarily select a `uuid` from a record that matches your condition — it will *not*, in general, select the `uuid` that actually corresponds to the `max(id)`. (This is explained, -ish, at [in §12.17.3 "MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`" of the *MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html), though that page makes it sound like you can only get this problem if you have a `GROUP BY` clause.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is using `limit` and `order by`:

```
select r.*
from Run r
where <some condition>
order by id desc
limit 1;
```